# Deleting cells by condition : code doesn't work

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop, conditional-statements

I didn't knew what's the problem with this , when i execute this code it doesn't work .

When i execute the code nothing happens:

```
Sub dltcls()

Dim i As Long
Dim lRow As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim s As Long


lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
s = lRow / 10

For i = 1 To lRow Step 10
For j = 0 To s

If i / 10 = j Then Cells(i + j, 1).Delete

Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

This is what i want to do :

for i=1 to N step 10

if i div 10 =0 then delete cells1

if i div 10 =1 then delete cells i+1

if i div 10 =2 then delete cells i+2

if i div 10 =3 then delete cells i+3

if i div 10 =4 then delete cells i+4

if i div 10 =5 then delete cells i+5

if i div 10 =6 then delete cells i+6

if i div 10 =7 then delete cells i+7

if i div 10 =8 then delete cells i+8

if i div 10 =9 then delete cells i+9

if i div 10 =10 then delete cells i+10
.
.
.
.

etc ....

Can anyone of you help me with this  ?

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint and checking your values?

Comment: I think you're looking for `If i Mod 10 = j`